# Subspaces of an adjunction space $X\cup_f Y$

Tags: general-topology

Here's what I need to prove:

> Let $A \subseteq Y'$ be closed subspaces of $Y $ and $X' \subseteq X$. Let $f\colon A\to X$ be continuous such that $f(A) \subseteq X'$. Denote $f\colon A\to X'$ by $g$. Then $X'\cup_g Y'$ is a subspace of $X\cup_f Y$.

By the universal property of a final topology with respect to $\pi_{\sim}\colon X\sqcup Y\to X\sqcup Y/\sim$ ($\sim$ being an equivalence relation on $X\sqcup Y$ generated by pairs $((0,f(a)),(1,a))$ for all $a \in A$), $O \subseteq X\cup_f Y$ is open (resp., closed) if and only if $\pi^{-1}_{\sim}(O)$ is in $X\sqcup Y$.

To prove that $X'\cup_g Y'$ is a subspace of $X\cup_f Y$, we need to show that for any closed subset of $X'\cup_g Y'$ there is a closed subset $O' \subseteq X\cup_f Y$ such that $O = O'\cap (X'\cup_g Y')$.

I maganed to prove that the disjoint union topology on $X'\sqcup Y'$ concides with the subspace topology $X'\sqcup Y' \subseteq X\sqcup Y$.

With that in mind, let $\sim'$ be the equivalence relation on $X'\sqcup Y'$ generated by $((0,f(a)),(1,a))$ for $a \in A$ and let $O$ be an open subset of $X'\cup_g Y'$. Then $\pi^{-1}_{\sim'}(O)$ is open in $X'\sqcup Y'$. I think that $\pi^{-1}_{\sim'}(O) = \pi^{-1}_{\sim}(O)$. Then there is open $U \subseteq X\sqcup Y$ such that $\pi^{-1}_{\sim}(O) = U\cap (X'\sqcup Y')$. Since $\pi_{\sim}$ is surjective, we have $\pi_{\sim}(\pi^{-1}_{\sim}(O)) = O$. Moreover, it can be shown that $\pi_{\sim}(U\cap (X'\sqcup Y')) = \pi_{\sim}(U)\cap (X'\cup_g Y')$. The problem is that $\pi_{\sim}(U)$ is not necessarily open in $X\cup_f Y$.

Comment: Did you write this correctly? I'd expect $f: X \to Y$, $A \subseteq X$, $Y' \subseteq Y$ with $f[A] \subseteq Y'$ and then $g = f\restriction_A: A \to Y'$. This makes more sense notationally too.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma There is really no difference. In my notes (tom Dieck's General Topology) it is written as I wrote. In your case $\sim$ is just generated by $((0,a),(1,f(a)))$ for all $a \in A$ instead of what I wrote.

Comment: This is Proposition (1.8.2) in tom Dieck which is *proved*. If you have problems to understand the proof, tell us where we can help.